# Has Google Chrome's DevTools removed the private [[Scopes]] property?

Tags: javascript, closures, google-chrome-devtools, v8, devtools

I updated Google Chrome to Version 108.0.5339.98 (Official Build) (arm64) and when I tried to use my DevTools to inspect a function using `console.dir`, the private `[[Scopes]]` property is no longer displayed.

```js
function outerFunc(g) {
  function innerFunc() {
    console.dir(innerFunc);
    return g + 0;
  }
  return innerFunc;
}

const func = outerFunc(90);
```

Until recently, the private `[[Scopes]]` property was displayed using the `dir` method alongside `[[FunctionLocation]]` and `[[Prototype]]`. The invocation of `dir` above does display the `[[Scopes]]` property in addition to the other two in Version 107.0.5304.121 (Official Build) (arm64) on my other computer. But in the updated version, only the other two private properties display, not `[[Scopes]]`. I've tried googling around and looking through the release notes but haven't found anything regarding its absence.

Comment: Yes, https://crbug.com/1365858

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue, it has indeed been removed and you will need to use a `debugger` statement and go to the sources pane. You will see a `scope` tab and there the closures will be listed and can be expanded if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still isn't seeing scopes, try updating.

They did remove it but decided to revert that change after some complaints. That decision was made months ago, but apparently I hadn't updated in a while. After updating (at least as of Version 112.0.5615.49), I'm now seeing scopes again.