# [[SCOPES]] missing on chrome dev tools

Tags: closures, console.dir

If i run console.dir(..) for a fn, chrome does not display the [[SCOPES]] on the dev tools anymore at least since the December 6th update! It shows on EDGE(ms).
chrome version 108.0.5359.125

this prevents me from getting the closure...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has Google Chrome's DevTools removed the private \[\[Scopes\]\] property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789952/has-google-chromes-devtools-removed-the-private-scopes-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same Problem, and you can inspect closure by using a debugger statement in your code. Later, press F12 to sources pane. You will see a scope tab and there the closures will be listed.
[sources pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA27i.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).